# Changing NULL value of cells to -1 with UPDATE query (HeidiSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I just changed the default value of a column in my database (w/ HeidiSQL) from NULL to -1, then I wanted to update every records that has a NULL value on this column to -1 but my query does not work :

```
UPDATE candidature 
SET reponse_Manager = -1 
WHERE reponse_Manager IS NULL
```

It actually runs without errors but doesn't find any NULL cells even though there are plenty. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing values manually for every records with HeidiSQL